# Как реализовать запрос в sqlite между тремя таблицами?

Tags: python, sqlite

Такой вопрос есть три таблицы `user`, `product`,`order_basket` связаны между собой связью many-to-many. [image: Вид таблиц].
Пытаюсь одним запросом получить код товаров из таблицы `product`.
Пример кода:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""
SELECT product FROM product WHERE id =
(SELECT id_product FROM order_basket WHERE id_user =
(SELECT id FROM users WHERE id_user=?))
 """,(message_user_id,))
```

при таком запросе возвращает первое совпадение.
Если разбить на отдельные запросы то запрос `SELECT id_product FROM order_basket WHERE id_user`
возвращает список из кортежей `id_product [(9,), (12,), (9,), (13,), (14,), (13,), (15,), (16,), (7,)]`  дальнейшая обработка идет через циклы, что хотелось избежать.   Возможно ли в одном или двух запросах реализовать получение всех совпадений по коду продукта?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня другие данные, потому что у вас картинка.

```
SELECT t1.name, t3.id, product
FROM (order_basket as t2 LEFT JOIN users as t1 ON t1.id=t2.id_user) 
LEFT JOIN product as t3 ON t3.id=t2.id_product
WHERE t1.name='user1''

user1   9   F00450
user1   12  F01678
user1   9   F00450
user1   13  F00735
user1   14  F92449
user1   13  F00735
user1   15  F90173
user1   16  F18000
user1   17  F99099
user1   8   F00510
user1   8   F00510
```

Comment: большое спасибо!!! Ваш ответ очень помог!!

Comment: Запрос не оптимизирован, возможно сначала вложенным запросом выбрать все orders c конкретным пользователем, а затем соединить левым с product, этим нужно заниматься и нужна база, чтобы была нагрузка.